# Button (GPIO) Pressing Logic in MicroPython

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I had another question open about iterative menu logic, and the problem morphed into button logic, so I'm separating them, since the original question was truly settled.

My code is as follows:

```
""" fit: a productivity logger """
import time
import sys
import os
import uhashlib
import machine
import framebuf
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

def final_print(sec,final_hash,final_survey):
    """ leaves the summary on the screen before shutting down """
    mins = sec // 60
    sec = sec % 60
    hours = mins // 60
    mins = mins % 60
    short_sec = int(sec)
    duration = (str(hours) + "/" + str(mins) + "/" + str(short_sec))
    oled_show("> fit the"+str(final_hash),str(final_survey),"//"+str(duration))
    time.sleep(30)
    oled_blank()

def timer_down(f_seconds,timer_focus):
    """ counts down for defined period """
    now = time.time()
    end = now + f_seconds
    while now < end:
        now = time.time()
        fit_progress(now,end,timer_focus,f_seconds)
        time.sleep(0.01)
#        if button1.value() == 0:
#             oled_show("","Ended Manually!","")
#             time.sleep(2)
#             break

def timer_up(timer_focus):
    """ counts up for indefinite period """
    now = time.time()
    while True:
        minutes = int((time.time() - now) / 60)
        oled_show(str(timer_focus)," for ",str(minutes))
        time.sleep(0.01)
#         if button1.value() == 0:
#             oled_show("","Ended Manually!","")
#             time.sleep(2)
#             break

def fit_progress(now,end,timer_focus,f_seconds):
    """ tracks progress of a count-down fit and prints to screen """
    remain = end - now
    f_minutes = int((remain)/60)
    j = 1 - (remain / f_seconds)
    pct = int(100*j)
    oled_show(str(timer_focus),str(f_minutes)+" min",str(pct)+"%")

def debounce(btn):
    """ some debounce control """
    count = 2
    while count > 0:
        if btn.value():
            count = 2
        else:
            count -= 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

def multi_choice(options):
    """ provides multi-choice menus for two-button navigation """
    for i in options:
        oled_show("> fit",i,"1:yes  2:next")
        # Wait for any button press.
        while 1:
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            if b1pressed or b2pressed:
                break
        if b1pressed:
            print( i, "chosen" )
            debounce(button1)
            return i
        # We know B2 was pressed.
        debounce(button2)

def oled_show(message1,message2,message3):
    """ displays a three line message """
    oled.fill(0) # clear the display
    oled.text(message1,5,5)
    oled.text(message2,5,15)
    oled.text(message3,5,25)
    oled.show()

def oled_blank():
    """ blanks the oled display to avoid burn in """
    oled.fill(0)
    oled.show()

sda = machine.Pin(4)
scl = machine.Pin(5)
i2c = machine.I2C(0,sda=sda, scl=scl, freq=400000)
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, i2c)

button1 = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = machine.Pin(3, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

F_TYPE = multi_choice(['30-minute fit','60-minute fit','indefinite fit'])

F_FOCUS = multi_choice(['personal fit','work fit','learn fit','admin fit'])

fStart = time.time()

if F_TYPE == "30-minute fit":
    timer_down(1800,F_FOCUS)
elif F_TYPE == "60-minute fit":
    timer_down(3600,F_FOCUS)
elif F_TYPE == "indefinite fit":
    timer_up(F_FOCUS)
else:
    sys.exit()

fEnd = time.time()

F_SURVEY = multi_choice(['went well','went ok','went poorly'])

fDuration = fEnd - fStart

F_HASH = uhashlib.sha256(str(fEnd).encode('utf-8')).digest()
F_HASH_SHORT = F_HASH[0:3]

fitdb = open("data.csv","a")
fitdb.write(str(F_HASH)+","+str(F_TYPE)+","+str(F_FOCUS)+","+str(F_SURVEY)+","+str(fStart)+","+str(fEnd)+","+str(fDuration)+"\n")
fitdb.close()

final_print(fDuration,F_HASH_SHORT,F_SURVEY)
```

In particular, you can see that I have two buttons defined:

```
button1 = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = machine.Pin(3, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
```

And they are primarily used to select from menus with multiple choices:

```
def debounce(btn):
    """ some debounce control """
    count = 2
    while count > 0:
        if btn.value():
            count = 2
        else:
            count -= 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

def multi_choice(options):
    """ provides multi-choice menus for two-button navigation """
    for i in options:
        oled_show("> fit",i,"1:yes  2:next")
        # Wait for any button press.
        while 1:
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            if b1pressed or b2pressed:
                break
        if b1pressed:
            print( i, "chosen" )
            debounce(button1)
            return i
        # We know B2 was pressed.
        debounce(button2)
```

However, I am encountering an issue whereby the buttons can only be pressed alternately. That is, when the multi_choice function begins, I can press button1 to select the first option, or I can press button2 to scroll to the next option, but, if I press button2, for example, it will not register for a second press (to select a second option), I can only then press button1... if I do that, I can only then press button2 next.

I'm certain this is just a logic issue I'm not seeing.

The buttons are ordinary momentary-closed Cherry MX switches on GPIO pins 2 and 3. They definitely work reliably, but something about this logic is wonky.

The following test works just fine, so it's not the buttons...

```
import machine
import time

button1 = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = machine.Pin(3, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

while True:
    b1pressed = button1.value()
    b2pressed = button2.value()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    b1released = button1.value()
    b2released = button2.value()
    if b1pressed and not b1released:
        print('Button1 pressed!')
    if b2pressed and not b2released:
        print('Button2 pressed!')
    if not b2pressed and b2released:
        print('Button2 released!')
    elif not b1pressed and b1released:
        print('Button1 released!')
```

I added in some print statements to debug this, and I can see the buttons taking and holding values. I feel like I need to tune in an artificial reset, maybe that's something I can do in debounce? I tried a few things, but I'm not making progress so far.

```
def debounce(btn):
    """ some debounce control """
    count = 2
    while count > 0:
        if btn.value():
            count = 2
        else:
            count -= 1
        time.sleep(0.01)

def multi_choice(options):
    """ provides multi-choice menus for two-button navigation """
    for i in options:
        print("below for")
        print("button 1 below for",button1.value())
        print("button 2 below for",button2.value())
        oled_show("      fit",i,"1:sel    2:next")
        while 1:
            print("below while")
            print("button 1 below while",button1.value())
            print("button 2 below while",button2.value())
            b1pressed = button1.value()
            b2pressed = button2.value()
            if b1pressed or b2pressed:
                print("below first if")
                print("button 1 first if",button1.value())
                print("button 2 first if",button2.value())
                break
        if b1pressed:
            print("below second if")
            print("button 1 second if",button1.value())
            print("button 2 second if",button2.value())
            debounce(button1)
            return i
        debounce(button2)
```

and the output of the above debug prints:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
below for
button 1 below for 0
button 2 below for 1
below while
button 1 below while 0
button 2 below while 1
below first if
button 1 first if 0
button 2 first if 1
below for
button 1 below for 1
button 2 below for 0
below while
button 1 below while 1
button 2 below while 0
below first if
button 1 first if 1
button 2 first if 0
below second if
button 1 second if 1
button 2 second if 0
below for
button 1 below for 0
button 2 below for 1
below while
button 1 below while 0
button 2 below while 1
below first if
button 1 first if 0
button 2 first if 1
below for
button 1 below for 1
button 2 below for 0
below while
button 1 below while 1
button 2 below while 0
below first if
button 1 first if 1
button 2 first if 0
below second if
button 1 second if 1
button 2 second if 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want PULL_UP.  When the button is not pressed, you want the signal to float low, which would be PULL_DOWN.

Comment: Ahhh, good catch, let me try that. You're awesome Tim, thanks for all the help on this stuff.

Comment: Interestingly, PULL_DOWN causes both switches to no longer function on this Pico (2040) device. Swapped back to PULL_UP and it's back to normal.

Comment: Have you tried a loop where you do nothing but `print( button1.value(), button2.value()` / `sleep(0.01)` just to watch what happens in real time?

Comment: (edited in main post to respond, since I can't insert the code here, but yeah, tried that, expected results)

Comment: Ok, yeah, I'm stumped. It's like the buttons just take a value and never reset.

Comment: They are always inverses of each other.  It's like "push A to set", "push B to reset".  Is it REMOTELY possible that you have a wiring mistake tying the two together somehow?

Comment: Confirmed, they're fine. I was thinking the same thing at one point, so just in case, I've got them wired to opposite sides of the board now, and to separate GND connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help from everybody here, I figured this out. Just needed to add a little sleep to avoid spill-over of the keypress from the previous while loop.

```
def multi_choice(options):
    """ provides multi-choice menus for two-button navigation """
    for i in options:
        oled_show("      fit",i,"1:sel    2:next")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        while 1:
            if not button1.value():
                return i
            if not button2.value():
                break
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

With both of your buttons tied to ground, and using PULL_UP the code is just:

```
import machine

button1 = machine.Pin(2, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = machine.Pin(3, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

while True:
    print('Button1 down!') if not button1.value() else print('Button1 up!') 
    print('Button2 down!') if not button2.value() else print('Button2 up!')
```

The logic is simple. Your button is tied to ground on one end and pulled up on the other. When you press that button it's going to connect the pin of the MCU to ground. When the button is pressed `value()` will be zero, and when it is released `value()` will be one. If you want `value()` to be positive when you press the button then you need to tie the button to the Vcc rail and use `PULL_DOWN` on the MCU pin.

All that debouncing code probably isn't even necessary, and even if it was necessary creating a loop to handle it isn't the answer. What if your button doesn't bounce ~ now you're just stuck in a loop. Get a 74HC14 or make a simple RC network if you're worried about bouncing. Assigning all these arbitrary values to button states and sticking buttons in loops that block your other buttons is just a bunch of noise. It's very simple: You have one question that you want to ask twice. "Is this button pressed" ~ so just "ask" that question twice and move on. It doesn't take 20 lines of code to determine if something is 1 or 0.

Aside:
You do not have a separate "GND". All your "GND" pins are connected to the same "GND". You have one power source right? Well, one is one. Cutting a cake into 8 pieces doesn't give you 8 cakes.

Comment: So this works well, just as the other does, in a vacuum, but I need help with how to apply this logic to a two-button menu system (one button for select, the other for next).